# How to properly deploy PHP app with Firestore on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-app-engine-php

I'm setting up a **PHP app** with **Cloud Firestore** on **Google Cloud Platform** based on https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore.

After deploying to **App Engine**, I see that "**new FirestoreClient();**" doesn't work, but the same code runs normally on **localhost**. How can I fix this?

The code:

index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

echo "Hello Firestore";

$firestore = new FirestoreClient();
$collectionReference = $firestore->collection('boards');
$documentReference = $collectionReference->document("b-1");
$snapshot = $documentReference->snapshot();
$data = $snapshot->data();
var_dump($data);

echo "Goodbye Firestore";
?>
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

Google Cloude Platform logs

```
GET 200 385 B 1,3 s Chrome 74 / I GET 200 385 B 1,3 s Chrome 74
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3 
A GET 200 107,58 KiB 2 ms Chrome 74 /images/logo.png A GET 200 107,58 KiB 2 ms Chrome 74
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "projects/plzwork",
    "description": "i don't know...",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.101.0",
        "grpc/grpc": "^1.19"
    }
}
```

Output with localhost

> Hello Firestore
>
> array(4) { ["headline"]=> string(1) "b" ["amount_of_threads"]=> int(1)
>   ["description"]=> string(22) "Flood and nothing else"
>   ["content_type"]=> string(7) "default" }
>
> Goodbye Firestore

Output with Google Cloud Platform

> Hello Firestore

[Database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62GDr.png)

Comment: Since the execution is stopped after the "Hello Firestore" output, it appears an error is occurring. Check your application logs in the Cloud Console for more details. Once you have found the error, share it in this question if you're unable to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be missing a `php.ini` file to enable the `grpc` extension which Cloud Firestore requires:

**php.ini**

```
extension=grpc.so
```

Include this file with your application. Check out these docs:

- [The php.ini file in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/php_ini)
- [App Engine dynamically loadable extensions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#dynamically_loadable_extensions)

Also, you mentioned not seeing any errors in your logs. The errors might've been reported in different files that aren't visible by default. Here's how to view them in the console:

[image]

Comment: Now i see authentication warning on localhost, and nothing new on gcloud(

Comment: Do you receive any errors? See the logs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/writing-application-logs

Comment: For some reason only informational log that I show above and after some time - response 204 for logo.png in head title

Comment: One more thing to verify is the project ID. You might want to also remove the line `putenv("GCLOUD_PROJECT=moondepth");`. Is `moondepth` the correct project ID and does the project have a `boards/b-1` document?

Comment: Project ID is "moondepth" and document exists, but when i change id to thing as "sdgsadwgf" - on localhost i get "Hello Firestore\n NULL\n Goodbye Firestore\n" and on GCloud i get "Hello Firestore\n" without errors

Comment: Last thing I can think of is to double check your `composer.json` file. Make sure `google/cloud-firestore` is in there and that the file is getting deployed to App Engine. Otherwise, it seems like there should be some kind of error reported after `Hello Firestore`.

Comment: i wrote code from - github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore tutorial, and also edit my question with composer.json

Comment: I think I was able to replicate your issue. Are you missing the `php.ini` file in your deployment? Updated my answer.